# Deep Hash Inspection

Tags: ruby

Okay so this is a bit complex but I need to loop through this hash to find if each element meets one of following conditions:

**The Value is a String**

or

**The Value is a Hash, containing Strings, Not Hashes**

or

**The Value is a Hash, containing Strings and/or Hashes**

or

**The Value is an Array**

**UPDATE:**

Something very strange...  [EDIT: this is because #collect is returning the hash's key-value pairs, which are arrays]

```
irb> my_hash['gd:name'].collect(&:class)
=> [Array, Array]
```

Looking at the hash below should the class of that inner element be a Hash, not an Array?

Inspected it looks like:

```
irb> my_hash['gd:name'].collect(&:inspect)
=> ["[\"gd:givenName\", {\"$t\"=>\"Thomas\"}]", "[\"gd:familyName\", {\"$t\"=>\"Chapin\"}]"]
```

*BUT IT BEHAVES LIKE A HASH:*

```
irb> my_hash['gd:name']['gd:givenName']
=> {"$t"=>"Thomas"}
irb> my_hash['gd:name']['gd:givenName']['$t']
=> "Thomas"
```

---

```
{
  "gd:etag"=>"\"Rnk7fjVSLyt7I2A9WhVQEU4KRQI.\"",
  "id"=>{
    "$t"=>"da513d38e88d949"
   },
  "gd:name"=>{
    "gd:givenName"=>{"$t"=>"Thomas"}, "gd:familyName"=>{"$t"=>"Chapin"}
  },
  "gd:phoneNumber"=>[
    {
      "rel"=>"mobile",
       "$t"=>"(480) 703-4887"
    }
  ], 
  "gd:email"=>[
    {
      "rel"=>"home",
      "primary"=>"true",
       "address"=>"tchapin@gmail.com"
    }, 
    {
      "rel"=>"work",
      "address"=>"tom@tornadodesign.com"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify if your inner hash must contain *all* strings (or hashes), or merely at least one string (or hash)?

Comment: I added an edit inline so other readers don't get confused -- you may want to take that chunk out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine Hash values.

Return true iff each:

- Value is a string or an array
- Value is a hash that is non-empty and contains only strings and/or hashes

A solution with some printing to show what's happening:

```
puts hash.each_pair.all?{|k,v|
  puts "key #{k} = value #{v} class #{v.class}"
  case v
  when String, Array
    true
  when Hash
    return false if v.empty? 
    v.each_pair.all?{|k2,v2|
      puts "inner key #{k2} = value #{v2} class #{v2.class}"
      case v2
      when String, Hash
        true
      else
        false
      end
    }
  else
    false
  end
}
```

If you don't care to keep track of the keys, you can change #each_pair to #values

Answer (score 1):

You can test the class of hash value.

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  if value.is_a? String 
    # do String work
  elsif value.is_a? Hash
    #do Hash work
  elsif value.is_a? Array
    # do Array work
  end
end
```

EDIT: updated with suggestion from Niklas B.

Comment: you should use `is_a?` instead: `[String, Hash, Array].any? { |t| value.is_a?(t) }`

Comment: ...or `Class#===` e.g. `case value; when String, Hash, Array then ...`

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer is_a? over class, or is simply for clarity?

Comment: @Alex: It also evaulates to true for subclasses of the argument. In Ruby, it's not uncommon to subclass builtins. Also, `any?` is preferrable over a `||` concatenation of very similar conditions in terms of readability and maintainabilty.

Comment: Look at the update. An issue is that the inner values are not behaving like hashes, but as arrays...

Comment: I think what is happening is that when you say:  my_hash['gd:name'].collect(&:inspect) you transforming the two hash values into a 2 element array. `>> a['gd:name'].collect(&:inspect)
=> ["[\"gd:givenName\", {\"$t\"=>\"Thomas\"}]", "[\"gd:familyName\", {\"$t\"=>\"Chapin\"}]"]`